# Hyperic 5.0 exporting custom MBeans in JBoss

Tags: jboss, export, jmx, hyperic

1. We're using JBoss AS 7.1.1, and Spring Integration.
2. We're exporting Spring Integration JMX MBean through JBoss native MBeanServer
3. In our company we are using Hyperic 5.0 Enterprise for resource monitoring

While trying to connect JBoss MBeanServer to Hyperic, with following JMX connection configuration

```
<config><option name="jmx.url" description="JMX URL to MBeanServer" default="service:jmx:remoting-jmx://localhost:9999" /> <option name="jmx.username" description="JMX username" optional="true" /> <option name="jmx.password" description="JMX password" optional="true" type="secret" /></config>
```

I receive NullPointerException in Hyperic agent

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.hyperic.hq.product.jmx.MxUtil$JMXConnectorKey.hashCode(MxUtil.java:495)
 at java.util.HashMap.get(Unknown Source)
 at org.hyperic.hq.product.jmx.MxUtil.getCachedMBeanConnector(MxUtil.java:435)
 at org.hyperic.hq.product.jmx.MxUtil.getValue(MxUtil.java:654)
 at org.hyperic.hq.product.jmx.MxUtil.getValue(MxUtil.java:313)
 at org.hyperic.hq.product.jmx.MxMeasurementPlugin.getValue(MxMeasurementPlugin.java:58)
 at org.hyperic.hq.product.MeasurementPluginManager.getPluginValue(MeasurementPluginManager.java:171)
 at org.hyperic.hq.product.MeasurementPluginManager.getValue(MeasurementPluginManager.java:269)
 at org.hyperic.hq.product.MeasurementPluginManager.getValue(MeasurementPluginManager.java:130)
 at org.hyperic.hq.product.MeasurementPluginManager.getValue(MeasurementPluginManager.java:122)
 at org.hyperic.hq.measurement.agent.server.MeasurementCommandsService.getMeasurements(MeasurementCommandsService.java:212)
 at org.hyperic.hq.measurement.agent.server.MeasurementCommandsServer.dispatchCommand(MeasurementCommandsServer.java:174)
 at org.hyperic.hq.agent.server.CommandDispatcher.processRequest(CommandDispatcher.java:113)
 at org.hyperic.hq.agent.server.CommandListener.handleConn(CommandListener.java:216)
 at org.hyperic.hq.agent.server.CommandListener.access$100(CommandListener.java:57)
 at org.hyperic.hq.agent.server.CommandListener$AgentDispatchTask.run(CommandListener.java:200)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

1. Where can I find source code for Hyperic agent?
2. How to export this right? I saw some old references, but they seems to be outdated, targeting JBoss 5.0, and not working for me. Is there a more comprehensive description for this task?

Answer (score 1):

You can find all the Hyperic (server and agent) source here - http://git.springsource.org/hq/hq/trees/master

I am not sure what you mean by 'export'. If you can describe what exactly you are trying to do, maybe i can help (i have written some custom plugins before).